# R: cluster strings with same begin

Tags: r, string, cluster-analysis

I've got the following vector

```
  words <- c("verkoop", "verkoopartikel", "artikelnummer", "bank", "bankinfo", "bankrekeningnummer", "artikelnaam")
```

How can I cluster the words that begin with the same letters?
So here, this would be:
verkoop, verkoopartikel
artikelnummer, artikelnaam
bank, bankinfo, bankrekeningnummer

Comment: is this exactly what you want or would http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming be useful to you? If so, the tm package provides this capability

Comment: I know stemming but I want to order the words like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution which first extracts the unique starting letters and then clusters the words in the vector using pattern matching:

```
words <- c("verkoop", "verkoopartikel", "artikelnummer", "bank", "bankinfo", "bankrekeningnummer", "artikelnaam")
l <- unique(substring(words,1,1)) 
l <- paste0("^", l) # the ^ indicates that the string should start with this letter
lapply(l, function(x,y) y[grep(x,y)], y=words) 
# [[1]]
# [1] "verkoop"        "verkoopartikel"
# [[2]]
# [1] "artikelnummer" "artikelnaam"  
# [[3]]
# [1] "bank"               "bankinfo"           "bankrekeningnummer"
```

Answer (score 0):

For two words to belong to the same cluster, how many initial letters should they share? The following example works with `n_init = 4` letters.

```
library(dplyr)

n_init <- 4

data.frame(words) %>%
  mutate(cluster = as.numeric(as.factor(substring(words, 1, n_init))))
```